# JGit checkout error while trying to examine repository with repodriller

Tags: git-checkout, jgit

I'm trying to run repodriller on all the commits of [Jsoup](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup). Each time I start the analysis of a new commit, I need to checkout the repository for that commit, so in my CommitVisitor, I execute this command `scmRepository.getScm().checkout(commit.getHash());`.
This command throws an exception 9/10 times, being

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.CheckoutConflictException: Checkout
> conflict with files:
> src/test/resources/htmltests/news-com-au-home.html.gz
> src/test/resources/htmltests/xwiki-1324.html.gz
> src/test/resources/htmltests/xwiki-edit.html.gz
> src/test/resources/htmltests/yahoo-jp.html.gz

Obviously, I have done no modifications on the repository, as I also cloned it fresh.
I highly doubt there's a problem in general with the approach because I've used the same technique on 10 java projects and only this one is problematic.
Is there a way to avoid the checkout of these files with JGit, or some alternative solution to the problem?

Comment: Maybe some files are seen as changed locally, e.g. sometimes Unix/Windows-newlines confuse git. I would do a `git status` in the directory of the repository on this state.

Comment: I'm currently working under Unix, but git status just says my work tree is clear, so I guess that's not the case

Answer (score 0):

If possible, check if the same checkout would work with a regular Git command ([`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) or [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch))

A possible cause of a [`CheckoutConflictException`](https://git.eclipse.org/r/plugins/gitiles/jgit/jgit/+/38327a54a86697458a1b326278e04833c105c00e/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/errors/CheckoutConflictException.java) is an unresolved merge conflict.
I would also check if you have the same file with different case (uper/lowercase).